# ActiveRecord query: order by a sum on an included model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

- Project has_many :items
- Item belongs_to :project

I'm trying to get the projects sorted by the total price of their respective items. Something like:

```
Project.includes(:items).order('SUM(items.price)')
```

With this code, ActiveRecord returns only the first project. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Project.find_by_sql "
  select projects.* 
  from projects 
  left join (
    select project_id, sum(price) as items_sum
    from items 
    group by project_id) as sums on
  project.id = sums.project_id
  order by sums.items_sum
```

Above SQL should work well on most DB systems (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...).

AR record `includes` is mostly used as eager loading solution. And I am not sure if you can use it that way - to order records of parent table.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the quick answer. No way to do this without going through find_by_sql?

Comment: It is possible to pass whole join string `:join` parameter. It is matter of taste but for me clean SQL looks better than mixed AR / SQL. Maybe Rails 3 AREL is more flexible as allows to write above SQL in clean AR. But I don't know AREL very well yet.

Comment: clean sql, while pretty, basically defeats the purpose of an ORM.

Comment: The purpose of AR/ORM is to save programmers time. For basics operations AR serves very well. For complex queries sometimes it is faster to write pure SQL.

Answer (score 8):

I've not tried the v3 stuff out yet, but I'd assume it would be something like

```
Product.joins(:items).group('products.id').order('SUM(items.price)')
```