# Order model by sum of child attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have Teams and teams have multiple memberships. Each memberships has points. I want to order teams by the sum of those membership points.

Example:

Team awesome | 10 points

Team good    | 8 points

Because:

**Team awesome**

- membership 1, points: 5
- membership 2, points: 5

**Team good:**

- membership 1, points: 5
- membership 2, points: 3

But i cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: Order them where? On view? In Query?

Comment: You want group and order or only order ?

Comment: in a view, in just want to order, i managed to show the grouped points but not to oder by them.

Comment: This is exatly what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312728/activerecord-query-order-by-a-sum-on-an-included-model

Comment: What's the schema of the data? Can you give any example code so that we can look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment.So I am specifying my point here .Is this team data and its membership data on same table or team data in one table and membership data in another table.Which database are you using.If it is MySQL or Oracle you can use aggregate function and CASE statement followed by order by to solve this problem.

You can use a query like this (If you are using MySQl database)

```
SELECT t.team_id,t.team_name,sum(t1.points) as sum_of_points,
 case  
 when sum(t1.points)=10 then "Awsome"
 when sum(t1.points)=8  then "good"
 else "default"
 end as credit 
from team t join team_membership t1 on(t.team_id=t1.team_id) 
group by t1.team_id order by sum_of_points desc
```

Comment: Membership is a table that belongs to a team. Team is a table that has many memberships. Points is an attribute of membership.

Comment: @user3562152 edited answer according to your needs.If you don't want any attribute from team table you can omit the join condition

Answer (score 0):

## In team.rb

```
has_many :memberships

def total_points
  self.memberships.sum(:points)
end
```

## In controller

```
@teams = Team.all.sort_by {|team| team.total_points }.reverse
```

## In view(example)

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= team.total_points %></td>
    <% if team.total_points >= 10 %>
     <td><%= "awesome" %></td>
    <% else %>
     <td><%= "good" %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```